# SonataAdmin - Page/Block rendering

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using the SonataAdmin Sandbox to test the CMS functionality, which is so far driving me insane

I have created a site and a test page. Now I'm looking to add content. There is a content_top, content and content_bottom

What I'm looking to do, is to create a 3 column page.

So within the `content` block list of the page, I have added a basic `sonata.block.service.text`.

I gave a layout `{{ CONTENT }}` and a `Class` of `left-col`

You can see this in the image below
[image]

Now, this is all good and it displays the text from the `text.block` fine.

I thought that by giving a `Class` when the block is rendered, it would render the `Class` field and a HTML/CSS class à la:

```
<div class="left-col">TEXT BLOCK CONTENT</div>
```

But alas, this just doesn't seem to happen

Am I right in thinking this `Class` field is used as the container's HTML css when rendering?

If so, then this is clearly a bug...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky and not well (actually, not at all) documented, but the `class` setting is actually a CSS class rendered only when the SonataPageBundle's configuration variable `is_inline_edition_on` is set to `true` ; which by default is `false` as the feature has been deprecated.

The inline edition allowed you to directly access the admin edit page of a block when you were logged in as an admin in the front only by clicking it. To quote the Upgrade document:

> ## UPGRADE FROM 2.2 to 2.3
>
> The inline edition (moving block around) from the front website has
>   been deprecated. This has been done for differents reasons:
>
> - if the html is not valid the javascript can mess up the code.
> - the layout management does not provide a good user experience.
>
> The code will be remove in further version of PageBundle. if you want
>   the old behavior you need to set to true the `is_inline_edition_on` key
>   sonata_page configuration.
>
> The `use_streamed_response` is deprecated, the option is still available to avoid BC break

There's no HTML wrapper for a block or a container, if you wish to add one, you should customize the template of your block(s).